# UTF-8 cross OS display issue

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I got stuck in Chinese string display on Linux.

I am developing an application which need to display UTF8 Chinese on Windows and Linux.

Below is my code. The string is parsing from the web.

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>

std::string utf8String = "1101\241@\245x\252d"; // "1101　台泥"
icu::UnicodeString unicodeString = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(utf8String.c_str());
const UChar* utf16Data = unicodeString.getBuffer();
std::wcout << "Decoded UTF-16 Data: " << utf16Data << std::endl;
```

On Windows env, the contents display is normal.

But on Linux, the contents will be something can not be identified like the value "utf16Data" below.

Please tell me how to convert/decode it well on Linux.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `"1101\241@\245x\252d"` That's no UTF-8. Not even close.

Comment: To be precise, this is a Big5-encoded string "1101　台泥".

Comment: The image you show is not "Linux", it's from some application (VS Code?) and it's solely how it is implemented. However, I guess that `UChar` aliases to `wchar_t` on Windows, to match the UTF-16 encoding used in wide parts of the OS. On Linux, `wchar_t` is typically UTF-32, so it can fully represent all Unicode codepoints. Not surprising that this is displayed differently. Further, when written to `wcout`, there may be no overload that treats this as a string, so it uses the `void const*` one that only outputs the pointer value in hex notation.

Comment: Do you also compile with `/utf-8` flag?

Comment: I'm going to guess that on a Taiwan or Hong Kong-localized Windows system, the default locale is the Big5 encoding.  That's why the so-called "utf8string" is displaying correctly on what looks like a Visual Studio or Visual Code debugger.  It is a simple byte string being decoded with the default encoding, which is actually Big5.

Comment: Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 2):

Use, if supported:

```
std::string utf8String = u8"1101　台泥"
```

or simply:

```
std::string utf8String = "1101　台泥"
```

Save the *source file* as UTF-8 and use the `/utf-8` switch to compile on Microsoft's compiler.

Then the same source should work fine on Linux.

Comment: Hi, the string is parsing from a web page. Can I decode it at runtime in utf8 on linux?

Comment: @WeiminChan It is not UTF-8-encoded. It is Big5-encoded.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, yes, Big5. If I add `-finput-charset` and `-fexec-charset` in my CMakeLists, can resolve the problem?

Comment: I tried with this `std::string strin = "1101\241@\245x\252d"`, and compile in Linux env, `g++ testBig5.cpp -finput-charset=Big5 -fexec-charset=Big5`, but not works.

Comment: @WeiminChan use the `u8` prefix on the string and it might work, but if the string is big5 you need to decode the string with big5, not utf8. The u8 prefix will generate a utf8 byte sequence and *then* the code you have should work.  You’ll still need the charset compiler switches for big5 though but you should really just decode with big5. I’m not familiar with icu to guide you

Comment: If you are downloading the string from a web page at runtime, then no amount of compiler flags will help you here. You just have a blob of raw bytes. You need to *interpret* those bytes as Big5 not as UTF-8. and then display accordingly. For instance, on Windows, *decode* the Big5 bytes to UTF-16, store the result in a `std::wstring`, and use `std::wcout` to display it. On Linux, *decode* the Big5 bytes to UTF-8, store it in a `std::string`, and display it with `std::cout`.  Or, *decode* to UTF-32, store it in a `std::wstring`, and display it with `std::wcout`.